# Ionic setting up subpages

Tags: ionic-framework, url-routing

I am trying to set up an app with multiple screens and some screens should have sub screens. the tabs are working fine and linking up with the correct template but the subpages are not working. i cant even browse to the set urls. when i click on the icons it goes  to the default i have set in the otherwise method.

**APP JS File**

```
  $stateProvider

// setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
.state('tab', {
   url: '/tab',
   abstract: true,
   templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
})

// Each tab has its own nav history stack:

.state('tab.home', {
   url: '/home',
      views: {
      'tab-home': {
       templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html',
       controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      }
   }
})

.state('tab.aboutApps', {
   url: '/aboutApps',
   views: {
     'tab-aboutApps': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-aboutApps.html'
    }
  }
})
.state('tab.aboutApps.pricing', {
   url: '/aboutApps/pricing',
   views: {
     'detail-pricing': {
         templateUrl: 'templates/detail-pricing.html'
     }
   }
})
.state('tab.aboutApps.features', {
    url: '/features',
    views: {
       'detail-features': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/detail-features.html'
       }
    }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-item class="text-wrap" href="#/tab/aboutApps/features">
    <p>Features</p>
    <ion-nav-view title="Features" name="detail-features" class="text-wrap"</ion-nav-view>
</ion-item>
<ion-item class="text-wrap" href="#/tab/aboutApps/pricing">
    <p>Pricing</p>
    <ion-nav-view title="Pricing" name="detail-priceing" class="text-wrap"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-item>
```

i am new to ionic and dont see why this wont work. i am thinking that there is a problem in creating the path or url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you are using:

```
href="#/tab/aboutApps/pricing"
```

on your ion-item,
change this to:

```
ui-sref="tab.aboutApps.pricing"
```

This is a directive that binds a link to a state.

You can read more about it here:

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref